# At this time, the ability to register and transfer Domains is not available for customers contracting with (AISPL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am using aws Route 53 for the first time . When try to register or transfer a domain its is showing following message (Register and transfer buttons are disabled from initial load ).

At this time, the ability to register and transfer Domains is not available for customers contracting with Amazon Internet Services Private Limited (AISPL). We will notify you by email when it becomes available later this year.

Do I need configure anything else before using Route 53 or is there any limitations if I am using Route 53 in free tier.

Comment: That message means the service you are trying to use is not available in the AWS India region.

Comment: But some of my colleagues can use the same

Comment: @mbaird It is also mentioned in aws console  that Route 53 does not require region selection.

Comment: If you think it is an error then contact AWS support. There's nothing anyone here can do to help.

Comment: Any idea, if this is still a case or can you register domain names from AISPL?

Comment: @HariKrishnaGanji No i am not to register domain from my account

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment-aispl.html - "If you sign up for a new account and choose India for your contact address, your user agreement will be with Amazon Internet Services Pvt. Ltd (AISPL), a local AWS seller in India"

I assume this message implies domain registration is not available yet to AWS accounts with contact address in India.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir . But is there any other option to access AWS Route 53

Comment: I think you can try providing non-Indian contact address when registering a domain.

Comment: But sir , both Register and Transfer action buttons are disabled .

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant the contact address of your AWS account. That's what seems to trigger an AISPL limitation at the moment.